# ANSI SQL equivalent of pandas `factorize()`?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

So I have to create user IDs from user's emails and all data is present on BigQuery. In python, pandas, its an easy one-liner as:

```
all_data['user_id'] = all_data['email'].factorize()[0]
```

But I cannot figure out a way to do this in BigQuery SQL. I tried using `RANK()` function but its nowhere close. Currently I am trying to make use of Window functions with `RANK()` but it seems a bit of a stretch to have such approach for such a simple task. All data is on BigQuery already so any advice of doing it some other way even outside SQL would be good too.

### A little context...

1. pandas factorize() function assigns a unique ID based on column provided so if emails are like `email1@example.com, email2@example.com, email1@example.com, email3@example.com, email1@example.com, email2@example.com`, it would return: `[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1]` and so on.
2. I have other columns in database as well so `RANK()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` seem not to help alone. I am trying to get around tho.

Comment: Do you mean `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: No. SInce emails can be repeated. `ROW_NUMBER()` alone wont do. Thats what I am trying to achieve right now

Comment: Then maybe `DENSE_RANK`?

Comment: That still encompasses whole row. What I need is to have a column based IDs generated from emails while considering only emails

Comment: Using `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY email)` should do just that AFAIK.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that woks perfectly. Consider adding that as an answer I can accept. As this is the simplest solution to this

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DENSE_RANK()` window function for this purpose:

```sql
select dataset.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY email)
from dataset
order by sent;
```

This would produce something like (using [Mikhail Berlyant's example data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66843476/466862) as starting point):

| SENT | EMAIL | DENSE_RANK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:01:00 | email4@example.com | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 00:02:00 | email2@example.com | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:03:00 | email4@example.com | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 00:04:00 | email3@example.com | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 00:05:00 | email4@example.com | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 00:06:00 | email2@example.com | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Consider below two options

Note, I am using slightly modified data example  - you will see why (I hope)

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '2021-01-01 00:01:00' sent , 'email4@example.com' recipient  union all 
  select '2021-01-01 00:02:00', 'email2@example.com' union all 
  select '2021-01-01 00:03:00', 'email4@example.com' union all 
  select '2021-01-01 00:04:00', 'email3@example.com' union all 
  select '2021-01-01 00:05:00', 'email4@example.com' union all 
  select '2021-01-01 00:06:00', 'email2@example.com'
)
```

Option 1:

In case if there is an order in which those emails should be set before assigning unique_id - for example by `sent` column. In this case consider below

```
#standardSQL
create temp function factorize(item string, list any type) as ((
  select unique_id from (
    select as struct recipient, row_number() over(order by min(sent)) - 1 unique_id
    from unnest(list)
    group by recipient
  ) 
  where recipient = item
));
select t.*, 
  factorize(recipient, array_agg(struct(recipient, sent)) over()) unique_id 
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

with output

[image]

Option 2:

In case if ordering does not matter much and you can just order alphabetically - consider below slightly [in my mind] simpler query with use of built-in [range_bucket](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#range_bucket) function

```
#standardSQL
create temp function factorize(item string, list any type) as (
  range_bucket(item, list) - 1 
);
with all_recipients as (
  select array_agg(recipient order by recipient) recipients from (
    select recipient
    from `project.dataset.table`
    group by recipient
  )
)
select t.*,
  factorize(recipient, recipients) unique_id
from `project.dataset.table` t, all_recipients
```

with output

[image]

Obviously in this case you can skip using udf and just simply use rabge_bucket within the final select (instead of within udf)

```
select t.*,
  range_bucket(recipient, recipients) - 1 unique_id
```